# When does convergence in distribution imply convergence in probability?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I was looking at the proof for the Delta Method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Proof_in_the_univariate_case) and there is something I am quite confused about.

It gives $\sqrt(n)[X_n - \theta]$ converges in distribution to $\text{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ where $\theta$ is some fixed value. It then says $X_n$ converges in probability to $\theta$. I can't figure out why this is true.

Edit: (a solution using Slutzky's)

I've thought of another way to see why this is true using Slutzky's theorem.

$\sqrt(n)(X_n-\theta) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution by assumption.

$1/\sqrt(n) \rightarrow 0$ and thus also converges to 0 in probability.

By Slutzky's, $(X_n-\theta) \rightarrow 0$*N(0,$\sigma^2$) = 0 in distribution.

Thus, $X_n-\theta \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

Comment: You dont need to post images, just write latex in the post directly!

Answer (score 3):

> When does convergence in distribution imply convergence in probability?

When the limit in distribution is a constant.

This is so in your case since one assumes that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\theta)$ converges in distribution, hence $X_n-\theta$ converges in distribution to $0$, that is, $X_n$ converges in distribution to the constant $\theta$.

Comment: I understand that convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability. But how do we know that X_n-\theta converges in distribution to 0?

Comment: Because, for every $x\gt0$, $P(X_n-\theta\geqslant x)=P(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\theta)\geqslant x\sqrt{n})\leqslant P(\sqrt{n}(X_n-\theta)\geqslant t)$ for every fixed $t$, for $n$ large enough, hence $\limsup P(X_n-\theta\geqslant x)\leqslant P(Z\geqslant t)$ for every $t$, where $Z$ is the limit in distribution. Since $P(Z\geqslant t)$ can be made as small as one wants, this proves that $P(X_n-\theta\geqslant x)\to0$, for every $x\gt0$. Likewise for $P(X_n-\theta\leqslant-x)$, for every $x\gt0$.

Comment: I'm going to put this in my own words to make sure I understand. Assume x > 0. Then, $P(\sqrt(n)(X_n-\theta) \geq x\sqrt(n)) \leq P(\sqrt(n)(X_n-\theta \geq t) \; \forall \; t\geq x\sqrt(n) \Rightarrow 0 \leq \liminf P(\sqrt(n)(X_n-\theta) \leq x\sqrt(n))\leq \limsup P(\sqrt(n)(X_n-\theta) \geq x\sqrt(n)) \leq P(Z \geq t) \; \forall \; t \leq \infty$ since $n \rightarrow \infty$. Taking limits as $t \rightarrow \infty$ gives that $P(\sqrt(n)(X_n-\theta) \geq x\sqrt(n)) \rightarrow 0 = P(0 \geq x)$. Similarly for x < 0.

Comment: Does this still hold if the limit in distribution is an indicator function?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine Not understandable, please provide a precise mathematical statement to be checked or invalidated (and, better yet, **post a new question**).

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine This is your idea of "a precise mathematical statement to be checked or invalidated"? Too bad.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine Of course not. Already when every $X_n$ has values in $\{0,1\}$, counterexamples abound.

Answer (score 0):

OK, $\sqrt(n) (X_n - \theta)$ converges in distribution to a normal distribution with expectation 0 and finite variance. Intuitively, since $\sqrt(n)$ goes to infinity, if $X_n - \theta$ did not converge in probability to zero,  the hole thing would blow up! Now, more formally, convergence in probability to zero means that for every positive $\epsilon$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ $P(|X_n - \theta| \ge \epsilon) \le \epsilon$. Now if this is not true, then for some positive $\epsilon$,  for all $n$ $P(|X_n-\theta| \ge \epsilon) > \epsilon$.

Multiplying with $\sqrt(n)$ we get, that for all $n$,
$
     \sqrt{n}  |X_n- \theta| $ will be larger than $\sqrt{n} \epsilon$ with probability larger than $\epsilon$ for all $n$, with other words, some $\epsilon$-atom of probability disappears to infinity, contradicting convergence in distribution.

Comment: "Now if this is not true, then for some positive ϵ, for all n"... This is not the negation of the preceding assertion.